# js forms oninput event

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events

I have a form with a multiple file field, and whenever files are upload to it, I append them to an array called `filesinput` (using the oninput event) and add them to a table to display all the uploaded files along with a button to remove the file. I intercept the submit event and POST the `filesinput` array instead. However whenever I click the Remove button, for some reason the form submits itself instead.

Here's my code-

```
window.onload =  function() {
                //var fileinput = document.querySelector('#inputfiles');
                var fileform = document.querySelector('form');
                var filetable = document.querySelector('#submitted');

                fileform.oninput = function(e) {
                    if(!e.target.files)
                        return;
                    var temp = Array.prototype.slice.call(e.target.files);
                    temp.forEach(function(file) {
                        filesinput.push(file);
                        filetable.innerHTML += '<tr> <td>' + file.name + '</td> <td> <button id="' + file.name + '" onclick="removeFile(this.id)">Remove</button></td></tr>';
                    });  
                }

                fileform.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    send(filesinput);
                });
            }
```

EDIT- the `removeFile` function-

```
function removeFile(filename) {
                var ind;
                filesinput.forEach(function(file, index) {
                    if(file.name == filename) {
                        ind = index;
                    }
                });
                filesinput.splice(ind, 1);
            }
```

It is outside the window.onload function, if that matters.

Comment: Try to return `false` from your `removeFile` function

Comment: Where is your remove function? If that's somehow connected to the code which process the form field you need to try `preventDefault()` either in start of your function or at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try changing `<button id="' + file.name + '" onclick="removeFile(this.id)">Remove</button>` to `<button type="button" id="' + file.name + '" onclick="removeFile(this.id)">Remove</button>`

Button type must not be submit, then only the form won't be submiited on on click of Remove button.